# How to create an ipa that can be trust on both ios10 and ios12 using Apple Developer Account

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ios-provisioning

I'm using xcode 10 and i have an app created using ionic framework that can be installed via OTA, this app is signed using Apple Developer Account (not Enterprise), ios 10 can download and install the app and then later on trust the certificate in Device Management (Distributed by automatic signing).
The problem is when it is downloaded by ios 12, the app is greyed out and when you go to the settings there is no Device Management.

I've tried several method like Sign up the device to apple beta software program and install profile. I'm think that when the installed app is distributed by enterprise account (in-house distribution), the profile of that app will show (correct me if i'm wrong). So i tried to create a provisioning profile and registers the device UDID (Ad-hoc distribution), after that the app is successfully installed, but i need to install the app without registering any device UDID.

Because ios10 can trust the app on device management without registering the device UDID, Is there a way for me to create an ipa with a "public provisioning profile like" using Apple Developer Account?

Comment: You can't install a non-enterprise ad-hoc build on a device unless that device's UDID is in the provisioning profile.  That is the whole point of Apple's App Store security model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the purpose of you doing so. If it's for testing purposes, the easiest way is to enable automatic signing in Xcode and run the app to your device on both iOS 10 and iOS 12, this will automatically add the device UDID to your dev account. (although the correct way is to get the UDID from iTunes and add the UDID to your dev account, which is tedious)

Later on, you can build the IPA and install the IPA to those devices.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Because apple rejected our app. i've decided to make the users install via OTA. the only problem is ios12 users cant install it. i tried to set it on automatic signing but it didnt install

Comment: Please share the exact rejection reason from iTunes connect. OTA download and you submit it to Apple for review? I thought you wanted to submit it to the App Store

Comment: Apple rejects the app because its not for public usage, the app required an account that can be avail in our company. so the apple recommend that we need to use Enterprise account. however we already buy for Apple Developer Account, so i've decided to published it in our server.